# Why is the pause button disabled in dart IDEA debugger

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

I am running the latest IDEA and DART plugin.

When debugging dart programs the pause button is disabled.

Is there a way to get it to work?

Breakpoints, resuming and stopping works.

Thanks in advance!

/Gunnar Eketrapp

Dart plugin version: 193.6015.53

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-193.6015.39, built on January 21, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.5+10-b520.30 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.1
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1981M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.tooltip.initialDelay=534
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart, com.jetbrains.jbre.bintray.downloader, io.flutter

Comment: you need to set a breakpoint for it work.

Comment: Ok so if I have a looping program there is no way to pause it !?

Comment: set a breakpoint at any line and then run the debugger; you can then pause resume or jump statement. Set a breakpoint at the start of the loop and every time the loop go to start of loop it will pause at breakpoint.